# Pandas Select Slice then map function over columns

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, dataframe, slice

I have a csv database which I am attempting to "sanitize" (replace private information with *'s) using k-anonymity. I am trying to select a bunch of rows which have the same value across multiple columns. If there is enough of those present I want to mutate the column values for those rows. currently i have

```
subset= df.loc[(df['Gender'] == g) & (df['Date of birth'] == bd) & (df['Postal code'] == pc), :]
if subset.shape[0] < k :
    subset['Date of birth'] = subset['Date of birth'].apply(lambda db: f(db))
```

This code produces the error

```
> A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame. Try
> using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
> 
> See the caveats in the documentation:
> http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
> subset['Date of birth'] = subset['Date of birth'].apply(lambda db:
> day_in_date_of_birth_with_stars(db))
```

Not sure how to fix this? I could repeat the lookup line instead of storing it in a variable but this is going to be run allot of times and want it to be as fast as possible.

This code also does not modify the values in the dataframe

Ive changed the code to

```
num_with_all = df.loc[(df['Gender'] == g) & (df['Date of birth'] == bd) & (df['Postal code'] == pc)].shape[0]
if num_with_all < k:
    df.ix[(df['Gender'] == g) & (df['Date of birth'] == bd) & (df['Postal code'] == pc), 'Date of birth'] = df.loc[(df['Gender'] == g) & (df['Date of birth'] == bd) & (df['Postal code'] == pc), 'Date of birth'].apply(lambda bd: f(bd))
```

This seems to run but takes to long for all subsets of (Gender, Birth date, postal code) in the database. Is there a way to make this more efficient?

Example:

I want to turn this

```
    Name    Gender  Date of birth   Telephone   Postal code Disease
0   *************   M   18-7-1981   ************    N2L 6B5 Avian Influenza
1   *********** F   28-11-1976  *********** N2L 4T6 Human Pulmonary Syndrome (HPS)
2   *************** F   4-3-1962    ************    N2L 1L9 Chlamydial infection
3   *************** F   10-8-1967   ************    N2L 4M5 Dandy fever
4   ****************    F   19-3-1963   ************    N2L 2L1 Chlamydial infection
5   ************    F   2-2-1979    ************    N2L 5J1 Scarlet fever
6   *********** M   21-1-1985   *********** N2L 1S6 Scarlet fever
7   *********** M   7-6-1977    ************    N2L 2Q9 Chlamydia
8   *************** F   9-11-1987   ************    N2L 7H9 Chlamydia
9   *****************   M   7-7-1989    ************    N2L 3B1 SARS- Severe Acute Respiratory Syndrome
10  *********** M   1-3-1969    ************    N2L 6N9 Malaria
11  **************  M   21-4-1990   ************    N2L 0B0 North American blastomycosis
12  *************** F   9-12-1964   ************    N2L 7F6 Chlamydia
13  **********  M   21-7-1960   ************    N2L 3P3 Chickenpox
14  ******************  F   11-10-1972  *********** N2L 6E4 Diphtheria
15  **************  M   25-12-1988  ************    N2L 1T4 SARS- Severe Acute Respiratory Syndrome
```

into

```
    Name    Gender  Date of birth   Telephone   Postal code Disease
0   *************   M   **-7-1981   ************    N2L 6B5 Avian Influenza
1   *********** F   **-11-1976  *********** N2L 4T6 Human Pulmonary Syndrome (HPS)
2   *************** F   *-3-1962    ************    N2L 1L9 Chlamydial infection
3   *************** F   **-8-1967   ************    N2L 4M5 Dandy fever
4   ****************    F   19-3-1963   ************    N2L 2L1 Chlamydial infection
5   ************    F   2-2-1979    ************    N2L 5J1 Scarlet fever
6   *********** M   **-1-1985   *********** N2L 1S6 Scarlet fever
7   *********** M   *-6-1977    ************    N2L 2Q9 Chlamydia
8   *************** F   9-11-1987   ************    N2L 7H9 Chlamydia
9   *****************   M   *-7-1989    ************    N2L 3B1 SARS- Severe Acute Respiratory Syndrome
10  *********** M   1-3-1969    ************    N2L 6N9 Malaria
11  **************  M   21-4-1990   ************    N2L 0B0 North American blastomycosis
12  *************** F   *-12-1964   ************    N2L 7F6 Chlamydia
13  **********  M   **-7-1960   ************    N2L 3P3 Chickenpox
14  ******************  F   11-10-1972  *********** N2L 6E4 Diphtheria
15  **************  M   **-12-1988  ************    N2L 1T4 SARS- Severe Acute Respiratory Syndrome
```

Only some of the rows have had the date of birth changed with *'s replacing some digits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's much easier if data, to play with, are provided.

Checklist of execution times:

1. **df.loc[...] df.ix[...] = df.loc[...].apply(lamda:)**
   loops 100 times - simulate 1600 records in 0:00:02.225785
   `The code in your Question`
2. **loc[...].apply(lamda:series)**
   loops 100 times - simulate 1600 records in 0:00:00.757525

   ```
   def f2(series):
       df.loc[series.name, 'Date of birth'] = '**' + series['Date of birth'][2:]
       return series

   query_df = df.loc[(df['Gender'] == g) & (df['Date of birth'] == bd) & (df['Postal code'] == pc)]

   if len(query_df) < k:
       query_df.apply(lambda series: f2(series), axis=1)
   ```
3. **loc[...].loop index**
   loops 100 times - simulate 1600 records in 0:00:00.666067

   ```
   query_df = df.loc[(df['Gender'] == g) & (df['Date of birth'] == bd) & (df['Postal code'] == pc)]
   if len(query_df) < k:
       for idx in query_df.index:
           df.loc[idx, 'Date of birth'] = '**' + df.loc[idx, 'Date of birth'][2:]
   ```

**Note**: I wonder about `if len(query_df) < k:`, should this not `if len(query_df) >= k:`?
You can gain additional speedup if you use a index with on of the columns ('Gender'|'Date of birth'|'Postal code').

**Output**: (Using your Data)
I show only the first 5 records and changed only record==1, as my query conditions are
'F', '28-11-1976', 'N2L 4T6'

```
               Name Gender Date of birth     Telephone Postal code
0     *************      M     18-7-1981  ************     N2L 6B5
1       ***********      F    **-11-1976   ***********     N2L 4T6
2   ***************      F      4-3-1962  ************     N2L 1L9
3   ***************      F     10-8-1967  ************     N2L 4M5
4  ****************      F     19-3-1963  ************     N2L 2L1
```

***Tested with Python:3.4.2 - pandas:0.19.2***

Comment: What you suggested does not allow me to edit the specific column in the row, or at least idk how to. I tried subset= subset[anon_col_name].apply(lambda db: anon_map_func(db)) but this did not set the values correctly in the original df

Comment: Yes, but Gender and Postal code both seem to disappear. The idea is to leave those column un changed and only star the date of birth. I could just be mis understanding the output.

Comment: Tried it and still doesn't work. The problem i'm finding is that the .apply functions seems to edit all the rows in the df when I only want to edit a subset of them.

Comment: After processing i output using. "print(df[df['Date of birth'].str.contains("\*")].to_string())
print(df[df['Date of birth'].str.contains("\*")].shape)" and get no results

Comment: Your answer seems to that the original dataframe and changes the columns value of "Date of birth" for all the rows in the original dataframe. What i want is to first query to see which rows match a specific condition. If enough of those rows exists, Then i want to apply a change to only that subset of rows in the original dataframe. The example i added to my questions should provide an example